# Conditional probability and complements

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know that in general
$\Pr(A|B) = 1 - \Pr(A'|B)$. However, I'm not sure how this works for the following exmaple:

Consider some random number $x\in[0, \infty)$. Now consider the conditional probability:
$$\Pr(x\in[z, z+\delta)|x\not\in[0, z))$$
for some $z\in[0, \infty)$ and $\delta>0$. Expanding this gives:
$$\frac{\Pr(x\in[z, z+\delta)  \cap x\not\in [0,z))}{\Pr(x\not\in[0,z))}$$

But since $x$ is a unique number, $x\in[z, z+\delta) \implies x\not\in[0,z)$. So this then becomes:
$$\Pr(x\in[z, z+\delta)|x\not\in[0, z))=\frac{\Pr(x\in[z, z+\delta))}{\Pr(x\not\in[0, z))}$$

Now consider the 'complement' event. That is:
$$\Pr(x\not\in[z, z+\delta)|x\not\in[0,z))$$

Expanding this gives:
$$\frac{\Pr(x\not\in[z, z+\delta) \cap x\not\in[0, z))}{\Pr(x\not\in[0,z))}= \frac{\Pr(x\in[z+\delta, \infty))}{\Pr(x\not\in[0,z))}$$
But then:
$$1-\Pr(x\not\in[z, z+\delta)|x\not\in[0,z))=\frac{\Pr(x\in[0,z+\delta))}{\Pr(x\not\in[0,z))}\neq \frac{\Pr(x\in[z, z+\delta))}{\Pr(x\not\in[0,z))}$$

Does anyone know what went wrong here? I can't seem to identify the error.
Thank you.

Comment: Given that $x \notin [0,z)$, it can be either in $[z,z+\delta]$ or in $[z+\delta,\infty)$, so the two probabilities are indeed complimentary. Not following what you did in the last equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be helpful to shorten the names of the probabilities, to make things less mentally taxing:
$$a=\Pr(x\in[0,z))$$
$$b=\Pr(x\in[z,z+\delta))$$
$$c=\Pr(x\in[z+\delta,\infty))$$
Then the initial conditional probability is $\frac b{b+c}$, and the complement is $\frac c{b+c}$, and you correctly calculate both. But then in taking $1-\frac b{b+c}$ you incorrectly take this to be $\frac{1-b}{b+c}$, not $\frac{b+c-b}{b+c}$.